# Can I run a single unit test from the command line for a Grails project?

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I've been running my Grails unit tests by typing `grails test-app :unit`, which runs all unit tests.  Is there a way to specify a single test?

**Edit:**  So far, everyone is basically saying the same thing, but when I do that, no tests are run.  Any more thoughts?

**Conclusion:**  OK, I was using the name of the test class, rather than the name of the class being tested.  Once I tried `Foo` instead of `FooTests` it worked perfectly.

Comment: What version are you on? I believe this feature was introduced in 1.2 release. http://www.grails.org/1.2+Release+Notes

Comment: can you post the actual command line you are entering, and the output? As you can see from the answers, this should work so there is a problem somewhere before the actual typing of the command. For example what is the name of the test? what is the name of the method in the testcase?

Comment: The first comment is misleading, you can test single Unit tests with Grails 1.1.1

Answer (score 44, accepted):

**Possibilities of things that might be wrong with your setup:**

- Your command order is incorrect. What works for me is:

  `grails test-app -unit Foo` (where my test class is `FooTests.groovy`)
- You aren't explicitly importing `grails.test.GrailsUnitTestCase`.

  I had some problems with it recognizing my tests when I didn't import this. When I was extending `GroovyTestCase`, things seemed to work normally.

### Working Example

Here's a sample set of tests that work for me. Perhaps you can spot some differences between them and your tests?

*Note: These are all run with the `testing` plugin installed*

**test/unit/FooTests.groovy**

```
import grails.test.GrailsUnitTestCase
class FooTest extends GrailsUnitTestCase {
    void testFoo() {
        assert true
    }

    void testBar() {
        assert true
    }
}
```

**test/unit/BarTests.groovy**

```
import grails.test.GrailsUnitTestCase
class BarTest extends GrailsUnitTestCase {
    void testFoo() {
        assert true
    }

    void testBar() {
        assert true
    }
}
```

**test/unit/my/pkg/BazTests.groovy**

```
package my.pkg

import grails.test.GrailsUnitTestCase

class BazTest extends GrailsUnitTestCase {
    void testFoo() {
        assert true
    }

    void testBar() {
        assert true
    }
}
```

**command: all unit tests**

```
$ grails test-app -unit
...

Starting unit test phase ...

-------------------------------------------------------
Running 6 unit tests...
Running test my.pkg.BazTest...PASSED
Running test FooTest...PASSED
Running test BarTest...PASSED
Tests Completed in 847ms ...
-------------------------------------------------------
Tests passed: 6
Tests failed: 0
-------------------------------------------------------

...
Tests PASSED - view reports in target/test-reports
```

**command: Foo unit tests**

```
$ grails test-app -unit Foo
...

Starting unit test phase ...

-------------------------------------------------------
Running 1 unit test...
Running test FooTest...PASSED
Tests Completed in 815ms ...
-------------------------------------------------------
Tests passed: 2
Tests failed: 0
-------------------------------------------------------

...
Tests PASSED - view reports in target/test-reports
```

**command: my.pkg.Baz unit tests**

```
$ grails test-app -unit my.pkg.Baz
...

Starting unit test phase ...

-------------------------------------------------------
Running 2 unit tests...
Running test my.pkg.BazTest...PASSED
Tests Completed in 842ms ...
-------------------------------------------------------
Tests passed: 2
Tests failed: 0
-------------------------------------------------------

...
Tests PASSED - view reports in target/test-reports
```

*I tried these in Grails 1.2.3 and Grails 1.3.4, both behaved the same.*

Answer (score 13):

yes there is

```
grails test-app -unit YourController.testSomething
```

where YourController is your controller and testSomething is the test method.

You should see something like

Tests PASSED - view reports in

Comment: Hmm . . . not working for me.  It tries to run the tests, but says passed, not finding it.

Answer (score 9):

Given a test class **foo.BarTests** you can run just the tests in that class using the following command:

```
grails test-app :unit foo.Bar
```

Or run a single test method within that class using:

```
grails test-app :unit foo.Bar.testMethod
```

Note that you do not include the word "Tests" when specifying the name of test class.

Comment: This is the only way which worked for me to test a single method with Grails 3.3.6.

Answer (score 3):

```
grails test-app -unit com.package.YourController.testSomething
```

you need to include the package name when you run the test

Comment: I guessed that, still didn't work.  Does it make a difference if it is a service class, and not generated, like a controller?

Answer (score 3):

This would work for sure, I use it every day

Following will run a single test

```
grails test-app :unit ExampleControllerTests.testName
```

Following will run all ExampleControllerTests

```
grails test-app :unit ExampleControllerTests
```

Comment: The OP specifically said that using the name of the test class was his error, but here your examples show doing exactly that. Plus your syntax looks suspect, with a trailing colon instead of a leading dash, though I don't really know...

Comment: Don't comment and vote negative if you don't really know, this works exact. Using the name of test class is no problem at all, I use it every day and i know it works. (I use grails 1.3.7)

Comment: I don't know how to reconcile what you said with what the OP said was the definitive answer. The downvote was not for the syntax which by itself I would have ignored.

Comment: Hmm, that works for me in Grails 2.0. I'm curious what version I was using 17 months ago when I was having this difficulty. @ErikE, I'd suggest that you reverse your vote, as this answer is correct, despite my previous assertions.

Comment: @Eric Thank you for the info! I commented in addition to downvoting to give a chance to fix the problem--if it existed. Now this has generated the chance for someone to update an answer or a question with the new information. I will never downvote unfairly if I can help it. Give some trust to the process, folks. :)

Comment: This syntax works for running integration tests also, like..

`grails test-app integration: TestSpec` etc.